# Ionic.io send push notification from node js server

Tags: android, node.js, push-notification, ionic-framework

I have successfully coded my ionic app to receive and display push notification from Ionic.io. I am deploying on a real Android device.

For this I am sending notifications from the web dashboard.

Now I want to move this mechanism to my node js server to send the push notifications from there to my ionic app. I am following the guidelines mentioned on [ionic io's website](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-sending-push) but it is not working. 
I have been struggling with this for hours and couldn't know what the blocking is, I am not sure if the POST parameters on the site are outdated or there is a specific way of achieving that.

What is the right way to send those notifications from a node js server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using [node-gcm](https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm) for this task.

To implement it I followed the tutorials [tutorial-1](http://www.sitepoint.com/push-notifications-in-ionic-apps-with-google-cloud-messaging/) and [tutorial-2](http://intown.biz/2014/04/11/android-notifications/).

> ### Update 2016
>
> I forgot to mention that the following [Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1owDaNQEtk) was extremely helpful too on the angular's side of ionic.

Comment: could you please share some code snippets through GitHub.